# Where in the wordpress database are the relationships between images and posts?

Tags: image, wordpress, import, export

I am trying to migrate a wordpress site from wordpress.com to a self-hosted site.

I export the data from wordpress.com to the xml file as one might expect. I then try to import the data into my wordpress installation on the self-hosted site. I check off import media when importing and everything seems to work after a couple of tries.( there are a LOT of images, so Varnish seems to gak somewhere in the middle, but it eventually all comes over). All the images are in the new database, but if I look at the Media tab in the Dashboard, there are no relationships between the images and any of the posts. Consequently none of the galleries defined in the original posts show up, although the directly linked image files in the posts show up fine.

So, I think the relationships between the images and the posts are getting dropped somewhere during the import. I've looked thru the XML file and can't seem to find where exactly these relationships between images (media) and posts are. I've also looked thru the database using phpmyadmin and can't seem to find where they're related either.

I'm hoping that if I can find where these relationships are stored in the XML file, I might be able to find a way to get them imported into the new database.

Would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I think (I'm guessing) images are "posts" in the db but of post_type "attachment", and are associated to posts via a post_parent id value.  (I'm commenting instead of answering because I'm not certain. But it's where I'd start looking.)

Answer (score 0):

What are the URLs of the galleries that are missing on the new self-hosted site? Are they still "yoursite.wordpress.com/wp-content/..."?

You need to find/replace in the database using phpmyadmin to change URLs that are still pointing to yoursite.wordpress.com. See  [How to Move WordPress Blog to New Domain or Location  »  My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/) and/or use [Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/), a good plugin that allows searching and replacing with Grep through all posts and pages.